# Как можно быстрее разбить целое число на простые множители

Tags: python, алгоритм

В одном из примеров указано из HEX данных получено 2 простых множителя:

```
17ED48941A08F981:
494C553B
53911073
```

У меня есть такие данные: `135AE76CD2FC210F`.

Как это разбить на 2 множителя?

Comment: А объясните, как из 17ED48941A08F981 получить 494C553B и 53911073?

Comment: Я не правильно записал свои данные, поправил. а в примере описано уже результат

Comment: Мой вопрос о другом же, а не о ваших данных. Нужно 17ED48941A08F981 перевести в десятичное число, найти его простые общие множители и их представить как hex?

Comment: @gil9red, 17ED48941A08F981 -> DEC = ‭1724114033281923457‬ и результативные 494C553B = ‭1229739323‬, 53911073 = ‭1402015859‬. 1229739323‬ * 1402015859‬ = 1724114033281923457. Как бы все правильно, а как они вычислялись я незнаю, вот и хочу узнать как реализовать на питоне?

Comment: @gil9red да как разбить получается 135AE76CD2FC210F = ‭1394681489206812943‬ на два простых множителя в питоне? (в ответ сразу распишите)

Comment: к словам "поподробнее", "желательно с кодом" и "сразу распишите" нужно еще добавить "да побыстрее, срочно надо".

Comment: @АртемШахматист такое ощущение то число 17ED48941A08F981 было наоборот получено через умножение двух случайно сгенерированных простых чисел, т.к. задача разбиения одного большого числа на два простых множителя является основной для взлома зашифрованных сообщений :) А для чего вам разбивать то число? В чем смысл?

Comment: Почитайте о разложении числа на простые множители (factorization), и о [алгоритме Pollard Rho Brent](https://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/pollard-rho-brent-integer-factorization/)

Comment: @gil9red, да я все с той же темой про которую вы мне вчера отвечали https://tlgrm.ru/docs/mtproto/samples-auth_key#prime-decomposition пытаюсь реализовать свой код для связи с телеграм по API без чужих библиотек.

Comment: @Эникейщик, забыл добавить. Прости.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Вот оптимизированная реализация (c) Antoni Gual Via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29744042/5741205) алгоритма [Pollard Rho Brent](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0):

```
import random
from math import gcd


def brent(N):
        if N%2==0:
                return 2
        y,c,m = random.randint(1, N-1),random.randint(1, N-1),random.randint(1, N-1)
        g,r,q = 1,1,1
        while g==1:             
                x = y
                for i in range(r):
                        y = ((y*y)%N+c)%N
                k = 0
                while (k<r and g==1):
                        ys = y
                        for i in range(min(m,r-k)):
                                y = ((y*y)%N+c)%N
                                q = q*(abs(x-y))%N
                        g = gcd(q,N)
                        k = k + m
                r = r*2
        if g==N:
                while True:
                        ys = ((ys*ys)%N+c)%N
                        g = gcd(abs(x-ys),N)
                        if g>1:
                                break

        return g    

def factorize(n1, sort=False):
    if n1<2: return []
    n=n1
    b=[]
    p=0
    sqr=int(n1**.5)+1
    mx=1000000
    while n % 2 ==0 : b.append(2);n//=2
    while n % 3 ==0 : b.append(3);n//=3
    i=5
    inc=2
    while i <=min(mx,sqr):
       while n % i ==0 : b.append(i); n//=i
       i+=inc
       inc=6-inc
    while n>mx:
      p1=n
      while p1!=p:
          p=p1
          p1=brent(p)
      b.append(p1);n//=p1 
    if n!=1: b.append(n)
    if sort: b=sorted(b)
    return b
```

---

Замеры времени:

```
In [19]: %time list(mn(1724114033281923457))
Wall time: 5min 30s
Out[19]: [1229739323, 1402015859]

In [20]: %time factorize(1724114033281923457)
Wall time: 227 ms
Out[20]: [1229739323, 1402015859]
```

---

```
In [58]: n = 67898771 * 492574361 * 10000223 * 305175781* 722222227 * 880949 * 908909

In [59]: %time factorize(n * 3 * 5 * 7 * 107, sort=True)
Wall time: 241 ms
Out[59]:
[3,
 5,
 7,
 107,
 880949,
 908909,
 10000223,
 67898771,
 305175781,
 492574361,
 722222227]
```

---

**UPDATE:** если мы знаем заранее что простых множителей отличных от единицы ровно два:

```
def factorize_mult_of_two(n):
    p = brent(n)
    return p, n//p
```

сравнение времени выполнения:

```
In [83]: %timeit factorize_mult_of_two(1724114033281923457)
45.3 ms ± 8.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [84]: %timeit factorize_Telethon(1724114033281923457)
104 ms ± 13.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: `factorize` простой огонь :)

Comment: @gil9red, да, мне тоже идея понравилась - сначала отсекаем все маленькие множители, а потом достаем базуку (ρ-алгоритма Полларда, улучшенный Брентом) ;)

Comment: @MaxU, Ваш вариант действительно быстрее. Возьму на вооружение его. Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

[Нагуглил код](http://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread1380574.html) и запустил для вашего числа, после продолжительного времени числа были найдены:

```
def mn(n):
    if n == 1: return [1]
    if n < 1 or not isinstance(n, int): raise TypeError
    i = 2
    while n != 1:
        if n % i == 0:
            n = n // i
            yield i
            continue
        i += 1


for i in mn(1724114033281923457):
    print(i, end=', ')

# 1229739323, 1402015859
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще есть такой вариант взял из модуля Telethon у меня отработал за 129 ms:

```
from random import randint
from math import gcd

def factorize(pq):
    if pq % 2 == 0:
        return 2, pq // 2

    y, c, m = randint(1, pq - 1), randint(1, pq - 1), randint(1, pq - 1)
    g = r = q = 1
    x = ys = 0

    while g == 1:
        x = y
        for i in range(r):
            y = (pow(y, 2, pq) + c) % pq

        k = 0
        while k < r and g == 1:
            ys = y
            for i in range(min(m, r - k)):
                y = (pow(y, 2, pq) + c) % pq
                q = q * (abs(x - y)) % pq

            g = gcd(q, pq)
            k += m

        r *= 2

    if g == pq:
        while True:
            ys = (pow(ys, 2, pq) + c) % pq
            g = gcd(abs(x - ys), pq)
            if g > 1:
                break

    p, q = g, pq // g
    return (p, q) if p < q else (q, p)

print(factorize(1724114033281923457))
```

P/S Данный код применяется с учетом что множителей может быть не более двух.

Comment: Этот алгоритм возвращает только первый простой множитель и результат деления исходного числа на этот множитель

Comment: @MaxU, не совсем вас понял, 67898771 * 492574361 * 10000223 * 305175781* 722222227 * 880949 * 908909 = 59024930745375542782952789961813397485416197210232171, и того factorize(67898771 * 492574361 * 10000223 * 305175781* 722222227 * 880949 * 908909) = (908909, 64940418397634463717437928287445054989461208119). Далее 908909 * 64940418397634463717437928287445054989461208119 = 59024930745375542782952789961813397485416197210232171. Или я что-то не так понял. В любом случае для моей задачи данные не имеют такого большого размера.

Comment: Т.е. если вы уверены что простых множителей отличных от `1` не больше двух, то можно напрямую вызывать функцию `brent()` из моего ответа и разделить исходное число на результат вызова функции, чтобы получить второй множитель

Comment: @MaxU, я понял вы задели тему более глобально. Это хорошо. Но в моем случае, всегда не более двух.

Comment: Какая у вас задача - найти первый простой множитель или все множители? И может ли быть более двух множителей?

Comment: Тогда алгоритм Брента все еще быстрее вашей реализации ;)

Comment: добавил сравнение в свой ответ...